# Mongoid database in camelcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm working with Ruby on Rails and Mongoid as datamodel.
All is working perfectly but I have and issue with a Collection in my database.

I have a collection named: "engineProfiles"

and I have my model class engineProfile.rb:

```
class EngineProfile
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   field :profileId, type: String

   embedded_in :role
end
```

and I have a parent Model class called role.rb:

```
class Role
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection: "role"

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :permissions
  embeds_many :engineProfiles
end
```

In every role collection, inside there is a engineProfile collection as array.

My problem is the name of the collection in the database, because if I change the collection to just "engine" in mongodb and do the change in my model class, all works fine.

any idea?

Comment: You say "My problem is the name of the collection in the database". What specifically is that problem?

Comment: in my database i have a collection named "engineProfiles" and the model class cannot recognize for the camel case

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, but in the future you should be more specific with youer questiuon. At least show the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I GOT THE SOLUTION.
When I have a collection with the name like "fooBar"

the model rb name need to be "foo_bar.rb"